# AngularJS change order of which directives are compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

As far as I've noticed Angular compiles things on a first come, first-serve basis which is kind of tricky. I made a directive which wraps some elements around and I want to have a link property which looks for stuff in the content.

For a concrete use-case: I am making a input label directive which looks inside the content for the first input and adds a randomly generated `id` to the `input` and a `for` attribute to the `label`

Here's the code:

```
// Find the first element with the attribute ng-label-target or the first input and links a label to it
app.directive('ngLabel', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      label: '@',
    },
    template: '<span class="ng-label">' +
                '<label class="ng-label-text">{{label}}</label>' +
                '<span class="ng-label-content" ng-transclude></span>' +
              '</span>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.id = scope.id || 'random-id-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000);
      angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.ng-label-text')).
        attr({for:scope.id});

      var target = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('[ng-label-target]'));
      if (!target || target.length == 0) {
        target = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('input,select,textarea')[0]);
      }
      target.attr({id:scope.id});
    },
  };
});
```

Example Usage:

```
<ng-label label="Text:">
   <input type="text" ng-model="page.textColor" size="5" maxlength="7" placeholder="e.g. #000" required />
   <input ng-label-target type="color" ng-model="page.textColor" required />
</ng-label>
```

This by itself works like a charm.

However now I want to auto-generate several inputs and have the label point to the first one. The issue is that when I do a `ng-repeat` inside my `ng-label` then `ng-repeat` code gets generated after my directive was processed so nothing actually gets found.

Therefore my question is: is there a way in which you can specify to angular to evaluate nested directives inside out instead of the other-way around?

Or, is there a batter way of doing this than I'm currently doing?

I made a fiddle to exemplify the order in which stuff gets evaluated. You see that the outer-directive has a smaller or equal value than it's contents (can't go lower than microseconds so I had to do a bunch of repeats):

http://jsfiddle.net/YLM9P/

Comment: sure looks a lot more complicated than need be... demo provided has too much recursion, provide demo using your directive and markup. You might find plunker easier to create angular demos with than fiddle

Comment: Why does the `id` need to be random? Can't you just use `id="name_{{ $index}}"` and the same for the label?

Comment: i don't want to specify the ID as I generally don't need it, that's why it's random if it is not specified

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the angular docs:

**PRIORITY**
When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

**TERMINAL**
If set to true then the current priority will be the last set of directives which will execute (any directives at the current priority will still execute as the order of execution on same priority is undefined).

So for your problem, I believe setting the terminal property to true will solve your issue.

```
app.directive('ngLabel', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    ....
    ....
    terminal: true
});
```

Comment: It seems like directives with lower priority are executed first.

Comment: doesn't work, been racking my brain for hours..

Answer (score 1):

This problem, like many others in Angular, can be solved by creating an additional directive:

```
app.directive('myLabelTarget', function() {
 return {
   require: '^myLabel',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, myLabelCtrl) {
     myLabelCtrl.doIfFirst(function(id) {
       attrs.$set('id', id);  
     });
   }
 };
});
```

With the `require` attribute, you can gain access to the controller of the myLabel directive higher up in the DOM.

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/91Yk9ZgnGCpF1VWk3MyX?p=preview) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can greatly simplify your code and eliminate your querySelectorAll (not terribly Angular-esque) by adding a function expression on the parent element (possibly passing in a parameter), then calling that function from the child element(s) within the ng-repeat.  The function would simply set a value that you would utilize and once it's set then you know you have the first one and the rest should be ignored.  I could be a little more specific if you showed what the final HTML should look like with your ng-repeat input fields in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register a MutationObserver that listens for elements added to the DOM. But this might be a little overhead to your problem - you decide ;)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // you get notified about added DOM elements here
    // check mutation.type if it was an insertion
    // then you handle the first node specifically.
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName, mutation.type, mutation);
  });
});

var config = {childList: true, attributes: false, characterData: false, subtree: false, attributeOldValue: false, characterDataOldValue: false};
observer.observe(element[0], config);
```

```
Demo              http://plnkr.co/h6kTtq
Documentation     https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
Browser support   http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver
```